# Execution of Thread not giving the right result

Tags: java, list, multithreading, operating-system

I have used there java class and in each class I have used override the run method.

Here are the classes:

```
package multithreading.marriageexp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Distribution implements Runnable{

    private int totalPersons;

    public void setTotalPersons(int totalPersons) {
        this.totalPersons = totalPersons;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of guests:: ");
        totalPersons = sc.nextInt();
    }

    public int getTotalPersons(){
        return totalPersons;
    }
}
```

```
package multithreading.marriageexp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Venue implements Runnable{

    List<String> venue = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> getVenue() {
        return venue;
    }

    public void setVenue(List<String> venue) {
        this.venue = venue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        venue.add("India");
        venue.add("Canada");
        venue.add("Australia");
    }
    
}
```

```
package multithreading.marriageexp;

import java.util.List;

public class WeddingCard implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Below is the details for the Weddings: ");

        System.out.println("Planned Venues to be picked from::");
        Venue v = new Venue();
        List<String> venuesList =  v.getVenue();

        venuesList.forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));

        Distribution d = new Distribution();

        System.out.println("And Total guests:: "+ d.getTotalPersons());

    }
}

class WeedingResult{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        Venue venue = new Venue();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(venue);

        Distribution distribution = new Distribution();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(distribution);

        t1.start();
        t1.join();

        t2.start();
        t2.join();


        WeddingCard weddingCard = new WeddingCard();
        Thread t3 = new Thread(weddingCard);

        t3.start();
        t3.join();

        System.out.println("--------------End of main Thread.--------------------");


    }
}
```

Here I am not getting the result of the venue list and also from distrubution class i.e d.getTotalPersons():

Here is what I am getting as result for passing the input 7 for the total number of guests:

Enter the number of guests::
3
Below are the details for the Weddings:
Planned Venues to be picked from::
Chennai Mumbai Pune --------------End of main Thread.--------------------

I tried resolving it, but didn't get the cause why it is behaving like it.

Comment: The `WeddingCard` does not use the instances of `Venue` and `Distribution` previously created and executed in different threads. Instead, it creates new ones that have never had their `run()` method called. Also, there is no way this code could print Chennai, Mumbai, or Pune, so you are not showing us the actual code you are running. Please show the code you are really running.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause of the error:**

I found that in WeddingResult, initially in the main function, a instance is getting created which is then passed to the Thread() - Here is where the input is received. After this in the run() method of the WeddingCard Class, another instance is created which doesn't invoke anything, just instance is there but with no values assigned to the instance variables (i.e, totalpersons & venue). Hence we're not getting any results.

**Solution:**

Instead we can start the t1 and t2 threads inside the t3 thread's run() method, this way initially t3 starts and then t1, t2 joins the execution and ends. Also instead of creating another instance, we can straight away pass the one and only instance that we've created to get the output.

**Here's modified code:**
(I assumed the file's name as WeedingResult.java)

```
package multithreading.marriageexp;

import java.util.List;

class WeddingCard implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Venue venue = new Venue();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(venue);

        Distribution distribution = new Distribution();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(distribution);

        t1.start();
        try {t1.join();} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        t2.start();
        try {t2.join();} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        System.out.println("Below is the details for the Weddings: ");

        System.out.println("Planned Venues to be picked from::");

        List<String> venuesList = venue.getVenue();

        venuesList.forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));

        System.out.println("And Total guests:: " + distribution.getTotalPersons());

    }
}

class WeedingResult {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WeddingCard weddingCard = new WeddingCard();
        Thread t3 = new Thread(weddingCard);

        t3.start();
        t3.join();

        System.out.println("--------------End of main Thread.--------------------");

    }
}
```

> BTW, I'm a newbie to java - Hence kindly provide feedback if the
> solution is not right. *Cheers!!*

**Sample Output**

> Enter the number of guests::  3 Below is the details for the Weddings:
> Planned Venues to be picked from:: India Canada Australia And Total
> guests:: 3
> --------------End of main Thread.--------------------

Comment: @Shoban Kumar.R thanks. It is working as I supposed it to work.